# Formula help on Check IN/Out System for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We are trying to create a loaner check in/out system for devices. I have 2 google forms, one for checking out and one for checking in that feed to different tabs on the same sheet. I have a third sheet for tracking for better visibility of how long the asset has been "out" for. I have it set up to change the status to CheckedIn once an item is listed on the check in sheet. I used NamedRanges to simplify calls back to previous sheets. I used the following formula to update status:

```
=IF(AND(CheckedOutDate="",CheckedInDate=""),"",IF(CheckedInDate<CheckedOutDate,"CheckedOut","CheckedIn"))
```

The issue I am running into is the NamedRange is comparing Row Numbers across the CheckedIN and CheckedOut ranges as opposed to cell values. Essentially it is working as a first out first in model, where I am looking for it to work off of the asset number checking in. Happy to share sheet if that is more helpful

I have tried numerous different CountIFs, indirects, query's, vlookups, etc.

Copy of Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19VI9peBBI-tD7NQSrcL8aiIeN9DfTgVfJp-U1d70M5g/edit?usp=share_link

Comment: Can you maybe fill in the expected output manually in the `Tracking` tab with a bit of explanation beside on what's the logic that needs to be applied to pull in this output?!

Comment: Thanks for the response @rockinfreakshow, I added a column for expected/desired status. The other "fun" wrinkle is ideally the asset will be checked out again after being checked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this formula out and see how its faring:

```
=map('Check Out Responses'!A2:A,'Check Out Responses'!B2:B,lambda(y,z,IF(z="",,IF(y<ifna(vlookup(z,{sort({'Check In Responses'!B:B,'Check In Responses'!A:A},2,0)},2,)),"CheckedIN","CheckedOUT"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been pulling my hair out for days trying to figure this out!